# Make CF7 redirect to specific forms instead of pages

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins, contact-form-7

After successfully submitting a CF7 form on our site the customer is redirected to a thank you page. But we only want them to go to the thank you page when they submit specific forms.

So far I have only been able to make the code do it for specific pages rather than for specific forms. Is it possible to rewrite or somehow change it?

```html
add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_specific_form_redirect');

function cf7_specific_form_redirect()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
('yes working');
            if (154 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-1/';
            } else if (155 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-2/';
            } else if (156 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-3/';
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: is there any redirection or just thank you message appear on same page? are you using any external plugin for page redirection?

Comment: I am using CF7. I am using the above PHP to redirect. If the form is on one of the pages in the code it sents you to the page /tak which is the thank you page. But I would like to change the code, so that it sends specific forms to the page /tak instead of specific pages. I have several forms on some pages and not all need a thank you page. No external plugin is used. CF7 to send the form and the above PHP to redirect. The thank you message is not on the same page, but redirected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the ids for every if condition to redirect.

I advise you to redirect for specific form ids instead for every form.
just replace 154 with your form ids as written in the shortcode

For E.g: **`[contact-form-7 id="154" title="Contact form 1"]`**

Code is tested and working fine with latest CF7.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_specific_form_redirect');

function cf7_specific_form_redirect()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
            if (154 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-1/';
            } else if (155 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-2/';
            } else if (156 === event.detail.contactFormId) { // Sends submissions on form 1070 to the second thank you page
                location = 'https://www.example.com/thank-you-3/';
            }
        }, false);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Hello! Yes this is exactly what I want. But the above code doesn't work. I added it to functions.php and changed the ID to my CF7 ID, but after filling the form nothing happens. No redirect?

Comment: i've tested this code it works fine, remove all the previous code of `wpcf7mailsent` and add above.

Comment: Hello Noman. I have tested it on two sites now, but it just doesn't seem to work. I have changed the ID to my ID and the URL, but nothing happens when you click. It goes in functions.php correct? What else could be the bug?

Comment: it should be on every `functions.php` with relevant form ids

Comment: It is. I added your exact code and wrote for the forms I want to redirect. But no redirect appears.

Comment: there might some plugins stop it add a `alert('yes working'); ` after this line `document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {`

Comment: Hey Norman. We tried the above code with your edit but still no luck. Look at my original post I added your 'yes working' part. Any idea?